# Make sure only single instance of winform application is runnin

Tags: winforms

I want to make ensure that only single instance of my winform app is running. Is there any way that i can accomplish it through visual studio 2008  rather than doing it in code behind

Comment: It is a built-in feature of VB.NET.  If you use another language then you'll have to write a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static void Main()
        {

```
        if (PriorProcess() != null)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Another instance of the app is already running.");
            return;
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());


    }

    public static Process PriorProcess()
    // Returns a System.Diagnostics.Process pointing to
    // a pre-existing process with the same name as the
    // current one, if any; or null if the current process
    // is unique.
    {
        Process curr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(curr.ProcessName);
        foreach (Process p in procs)
        {
            if ((p.Id != curr.Id) &&
                (p.MainModule.FileName == curr.MainModule.FileName))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in c# you can do something like this in your Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    public static FormMain MainForm = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE80}");
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MainForm = new FormMain();
            Application.Run(MainForm);
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            // send our Win32 message to make the currently running instance
            // jump on top of all the other windows
            NativeMethods.PostMessage(
                (IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST,
                NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);

        }
    }
}
```

and in your mainform put this

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME)
        {
            ShowMe();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void ShowMe()
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        // get our current "TopMost" value (ours will always be false though)
        bool top = TopMost;
        // make our form jump to the top of everything
        TopMost = true;
        // set it back to whatever it was
        TopMost = top;
    }
```

Comment: This works well in Windows 11 64 bits with Winforms @VS 2022  and .NET Framework 4.8; for anyone that is wondering about NativeMethods class, [there it is](https://gist.github.com/theaob/4078600#file-nativemethods-cs).