# C# Winforms launches Duplicate Instances when hit enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

Problem: When I Launch my Windows Application by clicking the **desktop icon** using Windows 7, and press enter key from the keyboard once the application is loaded it will open another instance of the application.

It seems that when I click the desktop icon first try and the application is launched the focus is still on the  desktop icon.

This scenario doesn't happen on Windows 10 , tested it several times.

I've tried several options already such as on Shown Event and Activated Event to keep focus on the form and text box but its not working

sample code below:

```
    private void frmLabelPNInput_Shown_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        this.Focus();
        this.txtLabelS.Focus();
    }
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

is there a way to prevent windows to open a new instance when the user press enter?

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: If you had read the documentation then you'd know that you shouldn't be calling either of those `Focus` methods. You shouldn't have to do either anyway but if you want to focus a form then you call its `Activate` method and if you want to focus a control then you call its `Select` method.

Comment: @John I also tried this Activate method , the issue still persists

Comment: Prevent a second instance from starting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010472/make-sure-only-single-instance-of-winform-application-is-runnin

Comment: Your app was probably always opening up two forms.  You just didn't see the second form on Win 7.  There are differences in the way win 7 and win 10 handles display forms.  If two forms are being generated than you must be calling the constructor twice in the app.  Not that the app is started twice.

Comment: @jdweng that's not the case ,I've double checked already thanks

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that `Activate` was a so;lution to this problem. I was simply saying that calling `Activate` is the proper way to focus a form so, if you ever actually need to focus a form in code, that's how you should do it.

Comment: This question is misguided anyway. If your app works as expected on Windows 10 then the app is obviously fine. If there's an issue with the user's environment then trying to fix that in code is not a good idea.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with a brand new project with an untouched form? Does it happen for both .NET Framework and .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my readings online , only solution that can be made for this problem is to restrict the application from running multiple instances.